# Why people use so many codes in competitive programming to write solution?

Tags: java, solution

Sometimes i solve problems in 'codeforces.org' and after every solve i see the solution of others.But most of the others solution contains so many codes.
For example:
I have written a code for the problem [Domino Piling](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/50/A/) like following.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int m = in.nextInt(), n = in.nextInt();
    int count = n*(m/2);
    if(m%2 == 1)
        count += n/2;
    System.out.println(count);
    in.close();
 } 
}
```

But `petr` who ranked in 2nd in `codeforces` wrote this solution like

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Template implements Runnable {
private void solve() throws IOException {
    int n = nextInt();
    int m = nextInt();
    writer.println(n * m / 2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Template().run();
}

BufferedReader reader;
StringTokenizer tokenizer;
PrintWriter writer;

public void run() {
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        tokenizer = null;
        writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        solve();
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

int nextInt() throws IOException {
    return Integer.parseInt(nextToken());
}

long nextLong() throws IOException {
    return Long.parseLong(nextToken());
}

double nextDouble() throws IOException {
    return Double.parseDouble(nextToken());
}

String nextToken() throws IOException {
    while (tokenizer == null || !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
    }
    return tokenizer.nextToken();
}
}
```

Here what we see that he used thread and his own customized input/output technique.But i am not understanding why he solved this solution like this and what's the need of own customized i/o technique??
There's one thing which impressed me most is,besides his long code his code execution time is better than me.His code execution time is only '90 milliseconds' and mine is '248 milliseconds'.

Can anyone explain me the reason behind it??

Comment: This is not multithreadding. He just created an instance of the class so that he wouldn't need to have each method `static`. I don't know why he's implementing `Runnable`, though.

Comment: The bulk of the extra code is to replace your Scanner, which may be more efficient  in terms of performance. He probably reuses all the code outside of `solve` for each problem.

Comment: Maybe someone who takes regularly part in such challenges has already some kind of pre-prepared code, as the name "template" suggests. Then only a few lines have to be customized.

Comment: This is a runnable instance but not runned with a Thread instance, so this is not multithreading.

Comment: How is that code execution time measured ?

Comment: `Scanner` is regex-based, while `StringTokenizer` isn't. So it performs better. This is meaningless outside of code competitions.

Comment: @ErwinSmout code execution time is measured according to the time taken by a program to calculate an valid output.

Comment: @RealSkeptic what is regex-based??

Comment: In order to understand what is really going on ... this might be a good use case to learn about profiling. Meaning: you could create a full "trace" of runs with small data for both solutions, and then see where time is really spent

Comment: `Scanner` is regex-based. It uses regex to find the delimiter pattern (the default is whitespace characters, but it can be set to something different) and to match the integer pattern when you use `nextInt`.

Comment: I don't know for him, but most of the time I use an IDE rather than the website's IDE. So I don't want to enter every inputs manually everytime for tests. I made a "MockScanner" and inputs some static arrays. Maybe he does the same.

Comment: @SHB so the time measured includes the time it takes for the user to tap the keys that provide the input on System.in ?

Answer (score 0):

Many coders actually have predefined templates for competitions. On codeforces, usually, they just copy that template into a file before even reading the problem they want to code and then code into that.

That bunch of code is actually fast input for Java. Some problems on codeforces require that. Petr must have just copied his usual template and coded that problem there, even if it wasn't necessary. The actual code Petr wrote specifically for this problem was the 3 lines function called `Solve`.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on a book called ["算法竞赛入门经典"](https://book.douban.com/subject/4138920/) and the author said that [this code](https://www.cpe.ku.ac.th/%7Ejim/java-io.html) is about 5~10 times faster than scanf.
Since I don't know java, I can't explain what this code means, but I'm sure you can understand it.

```java
/** Class for buffered reading int and double values */
class Reader {
    static BufferedReader reader;
    static StringTokenizer tokenizer;

    /** call this method to initialize reader for InputStream */
    static void init(InputStream input) {
        reader = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(input) );
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("");
    }

    /** get next word */
    static String next() throws IOException {
        while ( ! tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() ) {
            //TODO add check for eof if necessary
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(
                   reader.readLine() );
        }
        return tokenizer.nextToken();
    }

    static int nextInt() throws IOException {
        return Integer.parseInt( next() );
    }
    
    static double nextDouble() throws IOException {
        return Double.parseDouble( next() );
    }
}
```